What is the breakdown voltage of air (actually)?
Everyone knows that the breakdown of pure, dust-free, dry air is around 32kV per cm. Despite doing a lot of research I can't seem to find even a range of values for ordinary air that consistently appears across multiple sources (someone pointed out that the breakdown voltage of air varies a lot, so I am making it clear here that I am after a range of values). Also I think the curvature of electrodes plays a big role. Was the 32kV figure obtained with spherical electrodes or needle electrodes? I would love to do an experiment to find it out but I lack the equipment to generate the spark, let alone measure the voltage. I would be very grateful if you could provide a photo of an experiment, rather than quoting some website. I would also like to obtain figures for various types of discharge, like arcing/corona discharge.

So what is ordinary air to you? Do you live in moist jungle or dry desert? Do you live in dust free conditions or in a polluted city?

And the nominal value is 30 kV/cm (not mm).

I have corrected the mm/cm issue, thank you for pointing that out. And "ordinary air" is a RANGE of values, and I did say that in the post.

Have you done any Google searches? see this as the first result: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/breakdown-voltage-of-dry-air-compared-to-humid-air-how-much-of-difference.140393/

everyone knows... ... no, not everyone knows ...  in fact, most people do not know

The curvature of the electrodes is affects the peak field strength for a given voltage and distance between electrodes, but it doesn't change the properties of the air.

My professor claimed that 10^6V/m (one million) was a good estimate at STP, but that it could be an order of magnitude either side, depending on the quality of the air.

@SimonFitch Dave Tweed has given the standard figure usually cited: "The breakdown voltage between plane parallel electrodes separated by 1 cm at standard temperature and pressure is 30 kV." That sentence comes from Chapter 1, "The Art and Science of Lightning Protection" by Martin A. Uman. (A pretty readable book, actually.) I'll have to check references there to see what the circumstances are for the figure, though.

Skimming ahead I find more detail: "The breakdown voltage for a 1 m non-uniform air gap in the laboratory (e.g., vertical rod to horizontal plane) when the rod is negative (like most lightning), and the rise time of the voltage is about a microsecond, is about 500 kV (see Section 3.3)." and "Values of the critical electric field of $500:\frac{\text{kV}}{\text{m}}$ for negative stepped leaders and $300:\frac{\text{kV}}{\text{m}}$ for positive leaders have often been assumed, based on various laboratory experiments with long sparks in non-uniform gaps (e.g., Golde 1973, 1977)."

kV/ cm is an electric field value not a voltage.
If that is indeed a value for the breakdown FIELD then one can easily calculate the breakdown VOLTAGE for a particular geometry electrode by  calculating the actual electric field.
